# How to read and write multiple lines of a text file in Python

Tags: python, file, readlines

I am trying to read and write multiple lines of a text file in Python. My goal is to specify the rows which I want to be changed with the input I give to the script. The script is working when specifying a single row, but not with multiple rows.

For example lets say I have this file:

```
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
```

When trying to do the following for a single line it is working fine:

```
a_file = open("filename.yml", "r")
list_of_lines = a_file.readlines()
list_of_lines[1] = "Item: " + (input('Input: ')) + "\n"

a_file = open("filename.yml", "w")
a_file.writelines(list_of_lines)
a_file.close()
```

But I cant seem to figure out how to apply the same input for multiple lines of text file.
What I've tried but didn't work:

```
a_file = open("filename.yml", "r")
list_of_lines = a_file.readlines()
list_of_lines[1][2] = "Item: " + (input('some input: ')) + "\n"

a_file = open("filename.yml", "w")
a_file.writelines(list_of_lines)
a_file.close()
```

Comment: `list_of_lines[1] = ...`, `list_of_lines[2] = ...`?

Comment: `list_of_lines` is a list of lines of your file. You need to iterate over this list to get each line one by one. Or you can access each line with their index starting by 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thy using a `for` loop:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    list_of_lines = f.readlines()
    t = f"Item {input('some input: ')}\n"
    for i in range(len(list_of_lines)):
        if i in [1, 2]:
            list_of_lines[i] = t

with open("file.txt", "w") as f:
    f.writelines(list_of_lines)
```

`file.txt`:

```
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
```

Input:

```
some input: hello
```

Resulting `file.txt`:

```
Item 1
Item hello
Item hello
```

---

You can also use a `list` comprehension with the built-in [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) method:

```
t = f"Item {input('some input: ')}\n"
d = [1, 2]

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    list_of_lines = [t if i in d else v for i, v in enumerate(f)]
    
with open("file.txt", "w") as f:
    f.writelines(list_of_lines)
```

Comment: Great and detailed answer. Solved my issue and learned something new today. Thanks a bunch!